# Unknown UITableViewCellStateMask value when willTransitionToState is called

Tags: ios, uitableview

In API document, cell state mask document is defined as

```
enum {
   UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask                     = 0,
   UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask          = 1 << 0,
   UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask   = 1 << 1
};
```

However, when I push minus button when UITableView is in edit mode, argument of `willTransitionToState` is 3

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state{
    [super willTransitionToState:state];
    if(state == 3){
        //When minus button is pushed, value of state is 3
    }
}
```

Where can I find the definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

The `UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask` (A) is set to true. That is logical because you can still see the edit control. `UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask` (B) is also set to true, as you just pushed the minus button.

Thus,

```
(A) = 1 << 0 = 1   00000001
(B) = 1 << 1 = 2   00000010
----------------------------
(A) + (B)    = 3   00000011
```

Comment: Thanks! I misunderstood about mask. I will evaluate that like `(UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask | UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please do not forget to tick the checkmark.